Lifting linear automorphisms of a hypersurface to characteristic 0
This is actually a question which I think I have already answered myself but I am interested in finding a reference.
Let $X$ be a projective variety over a separably closed field $k$ of positive characteristic $p$. Let $a \in \textrm{Aut}(X)$. A lift of $a$ is a pair $(\widetilde{a},\widetilde{X})$ where $\widetilde{X}$ is a projective variety over a DVR $R$ with residue field $k$ so that $\widetilde{X}_k \cong X$, and $\widetilde{a} \in \textrm{Aut}(\widetilde{X})$ is such that $\widetilde{a}_k = a$.
I claim that if $(\textrm{ord}(a),p) = 1$, $X \to \mathbb{P}^n$ is a hypersurface and $a$ is linear with respect to this embedding then a lift of $a$ exists. First of all, we can take $R$ to be the ring of Witt vectors if $k$ is perfect, or the Cohen-Witt ring otherwise. There is some linear change of coordinates $L$ so that $LaL^{-1}$ is diagonal, with eigenvalues being roots of unity of order coprime to $p$. Write $X' = L(X)$ as well. Recall that the Teichmuller lift is multiplicative and sends roots of unity to roots of unity of the same order. Hypersurfaces such as $L(X)$ can be lifted to the (Cohen)-Witt ring $R$, and we may write $\widetilde{L(X)}$ for this lift. Then we can also lift the diagonal matrix $LaL^{-1}$ using the Teichmuller lift to get a diagonal matrix $D$ over $R$. I claim that $(D,\widetilde{L(X)})$ is a lift of $a$.
I'm just curious if the result extends to other scenarios?
